# How to use vc++ class library in some other project?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I have created a class library whcih has simple Dispaly().

I need to use that display function in some other Vc++ project how can i do this ??

Plz help me Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build it as either a static or dynamic library and then add this library to the build properties of the other project. You will also need to point the new project to the appropriate class header files.

Comment: I used the .net f/w namesapces in Dispaly() can i use like that

Comment: Yes - depending on the type of the new project you may need to manually add in libraries for the .NET framework if the project setup wizard didn't do that for you.